# JSON serialization in Utilities

Tags: google-apps-script

Need clarification on the following code.

As I recall, sometime back Utilities.jsonStringify() did not save functions in JSON objects. But now they are saving it as a string ("resultFn":"\nfunction (pageNum, pageSize, filter) {\n    return [{a:\"abc1\", b:\"bcd1\"}, {a:\"abc2\", b:\"bcd2\"}, {a:\"abc3\", b:\"bcd3\"}, {a:\"abc4\", b:\"bcd4\"}];\n}).

And using eval(), the function can be brought back (see my code in myFunction). It works fine for me, at least for trivial examples.

Q: AFAIK, function serialization is outside the standard. And since this is not documented, can we rely on Google for this as API contract?

Can I also add - this will save me a lot of lines of code :)

```
var fnResults = function(pageNum, pageSize, filter) {
    return [
        { a: "abc1", b: "bcd1" },
        { a: "abc2", b: "bcd2" },
        { a: "abc3", b: "bcd3" },
        { a: "abc4", b: "bcd4" },  
    ];
};

var TestConfig = {
    pagerId: "TestId",
    pageSize: 10,
    widgetWidth: "15cm",
    filterOptions: [],
    resultFn: fnResults,
};


function myFunction() {
    Logger.log(TestConfig.resultFn(1,2,3));
    var s = Utilities.jsonStringify(TestConfig);
    Logger.log(s);
    var o = Utilities.jsonParse(s);
    Logger.log(eval(o.resultFn)(1,2,3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, and you should not rely on it.

Comment: Hi Corey and thanks for the reply. Can I ask if your reply is official Google position or because its outside of the JSON standard? If Google were to carry on as their own "enhancement" I can still make good use of this - so long as Google agrees not to change it.